# Рассчитать расстояние автомобильного пути по 2 локациям Google maps.

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>

        <script>
        var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.904091364647186, 34.80847507377776);
        var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.9170757, 34.80850970000001);

        console.log(calcDistance(p1, p2));

        //calculates distance between two points in km's
        function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
          return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2)).toFixed(2);
        }

        </script>
```

Использую этот скрипт для вычисление расстояние между 2 точками, могу ли я как то вычислить расстояние с учетом автомобильного пути?

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы найти расстояние с учетом автомобильного пути вам нужно

1. Получить ключ [на официальном сайте Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).
2. Добавить скрипт Google Map API используя вам ключ, вот пример: 

   `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>`
3. Использовать объект `DirectionsService` для вычисления пути

   ```
       function initMap() {
       var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.904091364647186, 34.80847507377776);
       var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.9170757, 34.80850970000001);

       calcDistance(p1, p2);

       //calculates distance between two points in km's
      function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
          var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
          directionsService.route({
              origin: p1,
              destination: p2,
              travelMode: 'DRIVING'
          }, function(response, status) {
              if (status === 'OK') {
                  console.log(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);
              } else {
                  console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
              }
         });
       }
   }
   ```

   В вашем примере у меня получилось 1986 метров.

Comment: А как это можно сделать на react js?

Comment: В чем именно проблема? Если в вызове функции initMap, то вы можете установить google map api через npm, например [google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps)